# Github Copilot Chat v0.10 unable list slash commands when type / in Start Inline Chat

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

In my VS Code, I run `Start Inline Chat` in the editor.

[image]

Then I type `/` and expected to get all the available slash commands. But it actually will not display the drop-down list.

[image]

I saw a video from GitHub's video. It does given a list of commands when type slash (`/`).

https://youtu.be/AAT4zCfzsHI?si=a4qAuv01oHe6NeNV&t=1024

[image]

Here is my vscode version info:

```
Version: 1.84.1 (user setup)
Commit: 2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f
Date: 2023-11-06T12:35:59.022Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

My GitHub Copilot Chat version is `v0.10.1`.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: the latest version of copilot chat is 0.11.2023111601. try updating.

Comment: I tried Visual Studio Code - Insiders with GitHub Copilot Chat v0.11.2023111701. It do works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asker was trying the feature on a version of GitHub Copilot Chat that didn't have the feature yet. The solution was to update the GitHub Copilot Chat extension to the latest version (circa v0.11 from v0.10). Unfortunately I can't find a changelog for the extension. The closest thing I can get to docs talking about it time-wise is the VS Code 1.84 release notes: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_streaming-inline-chat.